# LevelDB unexpected sorting results

Tags: node.js, leveldb

The levelup API (https://github.com/Level/levelup#api) describes the sorting options as:

> You can supply an options object as the first parameter to
>   createReadStream() with the following properties:
>
> gt (greater than), gte (greater than or equal) define the lower bound
>   of the range to be streamed. Only entries where the key is greater
>   than (or equal to) this option will be included in the range.
>
> lt (less than), lte (less than or equal) define the higher bound of
>   the range to be streamed. Only entries where the key is less than (or
>   equal to) this option will be included in the range.

I setup a quick test to try to debug the odd results I'm seeing in my levelDB-based kv store.

```
const level = require('level');
const levelDb = level('./db');

const put = (key, val) => new Promise(resolve => {
    levelDb.put(key, val, err => {
        if (err) resolve(false);
        resolve(true);
    });
});

const stream = options => new Promise(resolve => {
    let output = [];
    levelDb.createReadStream(options)
        .on('data', data => { output.push({ k: data.key, v: data.value }); })
        .on('end', () => { resolve(output); });
});

const runTest = async() => {
    await put('a', 123);
    await put('b:ab', 123);
    await put('b:X345345:234', 123);
    await put('c', 123);

    const results = await stream({ gte: 'b:0', lte:'b:Z' });
    console.log(results);
}

runTest();
```

I have a key `b:ab` and a key `b:X345345:234`, which would seemingly fall between `b:0` and `b:Z`, yet I only receive `b:X345345:234` in the results.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b:ab doesn't fall within b:0 and b:Z because `a` comes after `Z` in the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  Thanks!